# Let $S$ be the set of points whose coordinates $x$ and $y$ are integers that satisfy $0\le x\le3,$ $0\le y\le4$. Two distinct points .....

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Let $S$ be the set of points whose coordinates $x,$ $y$ are integers that satisfy $0\le x\le3,$ $0\le y\le4$.  Two distinct points are randomly chosen from $S.$ The probability that the midpoint of the segment they determine also belongs to $S$ is?

My approach:

I tried finding the probability of the points ***not*** belonging to $S$ as that makes the problem easier.

Let the two points be $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$

Since $a,b,c,d$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}$, their midpoint *won't* belong to $S$ if $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,d\}$ are both: one odd one even. (Like $a$ is odd, $c$ is even or vice versa, same for $(b,d)$.)

Now, for selecting $a,c$:

$_2C_1$ (for selecting which one is odd and which is even) $\ast\, _2C_1 \ast\, _2C_1$ ( since for $x$ there are $2$ even numbers: $0,2$ and $2$ odd numbers: $1,3$)

Similarly for selecting $b,d$:

$_2C_1 \ast\, _3C_1 \ast\, _2C_1$ (since for $y$ there are $3$ even numbers and $2$ odd numbers)

Total favourable cases = $_2C_1 \ast\, _2C_1 \ast\, _2C_1 \ast\, _2C_1 \ast\, _3C_1 \ast\, _2C_1 = 96$(Multiplying both)

Total cases = $_{20}C_2 = 190$

Therefore probability = $96/190 = 48/95$

Required probability = $1 - 48/95 = 47/95$

But the given answer is $21/95$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Should the coordinates not be of the form (x,y,z)

Comment: yes i corrected the question

Comment: Can I ask where the question and solution is from because I get a completely different answer!

Comment: While I can't count this myself I can use Mathematica to do so and have verified that there are 42 such pairs, hence 42/190=21/95 as indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just count, for each possible midpoint, the number of pairs with that midpoint, which is not too hard to do manually:

```
0 1 2 1 0
1 4 7 4 1
1 4 7 4 1
0 1 2 1 0
```

So there are $42$ admissible pairs out of $\binom{20}2$ for a probability of $\frac{21}{95}$.

Comment: I wonder what this distribution of counts per vertex looks like for larger boxes (i.e., larger upper bounds on $x,y$). Playing around numerically it looks like, if one takes a slice at fixed $x$, the counts for different $y$ rises and then falls like a pyramid.

Comment: could you explain what that grid is?

Comment: @Mathslover The points in $S$.